# How can I convert an RGB integer to the corresponding RGB tuple (R,G,B)?

Tags: objective-c, c

How can I convert an ARGB integer to the corresponding ARGB tuple (A,R,G,B)?

I receive some XML where a color tag is given with some integer value (e.g -16777216). I need to draw a rectangle filled with that color. But I am unable to retrieve values of the A,R,G,B components from the integer value.

Comment: fine I wil stopped all these,now will you plz give me solution of my problem.....

Answer (score 3):

If the integer is ARGB I think it should be:

```
unsigned char b = color & 0x000000FF;
unsigned char g = (color>> 8) & 0x000000FF;
unsigned char r = (color>>16) & 0x000000FF;
unsigned char a = (color>>24) & 0x000000FF;
```

Comment: it works but in place of flora green it gives me yellow..is there is problem with some alpha value??

Comment: @Greshi Gupta
Can you provide the colour value you're trying to convert? This should work for 32 bit ARGB colour. Yellow is a mix of red and green, so perhaps your color values have a lower bit depth or something. AFAIK alpha values should not affect the colour hue.

Comment: -8323328 is value of light green. but when i convert this i get light yellow.

Comment: I'm guessing you're dealing with 16 or 24 bit colour. You should probably check the bitdepth.

Comment: thanks Drdipshit..i got the answer..actually i needed to divide it by 255,because I am using core graphic classes where value of RGB lies between 0-1. 

thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use bitwise AND and shift right to select individual bytes from the 32-bit integer.

```
uint32_t color = -16777216;

uint8_t b = (color & 0x000000ff);
uint8_t g = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
uint8_t r = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
uint8_t a = (color & 0xff000000) >> 24;
```

Comment: BTW, IMO it'd be slightly less error-prone if you shifted before masking, and then all the masks can be `0xFF`.

Comment: You may be right — I’ve just always done it this way. Would you elaborate on why you would consider this more error-prone? I hope there’s not a subtle bug I’m missing.

Comment: @Todd: Probably because it's easier to mistype e.g. 0x00ff0000 than to type 0xff. Also, the larger masks are very likely to be more expensive code-wise.

Comment: it works , but color is different..
e.g. -65536 is value for red that I receive from window system. when I used the above steps to convert ARGB into A,R,G,B. it gives some other color not the red one

Comment: even in case of red it gives
a=0
r=0
g=0
b=0
instead of r=255

Comment: @unwind: That’s what I assumed. It might be easy to type one too many 0’s or f’s. Also, you were right: it does produce a few more instructions. Interesting.

Comment: no Todd,my data is in ARGB format. because I am sending in that format only.

Comment: @Greshi Try to invert the variables. In my case, color was in BGR order, ie:

unsigned r = (cor >> 16) & 0x000000FF;
unsigned g = (cor >> 8) & 0x000000FF;
unsigned b = cor & 0x000000FF;

Answer (score 1):

You can try use unions. Something like this

```
struct color
{
  unsigned char alpha:8;
  unsigned char r:8;
  unsigned char g:8;
  unsigned char b:8;
};

union
{
  struct color selector;
  unsigned int base:32;
};
```

Comment: +1 - This could be used to provide more information about questions on unions at SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
unsigned a = (color >> 24) & 0x000000FF;
unsigned b = (color >> 16) & 0x000000FF;
unsigned g = (color >> 8) & 0x000000FF;
unsigned r = color & 0x000000FF;

CGFloat rf = (CGFloat)r / 255.f;
CGFloat gf = (CGFloat)g / 255.f;
CGFloat bf = (CGFloat)b / 255.f;
CGFloat af = (CGFloat)a / 255.f;
```

Comment: I don't know if it's got something to do with the format my client provided but I had to swap the names of b and r to make it work.